# Combining google analytics and mixpanel click trigger in single jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, mixpanel

Totally newbie here. I know it's really basic things, but I'm trying to combine both GA and mixpanel in one unobtrusive jQuery function. I've tried inline onClick method and It's works flawlessly, but I need unobtrusive solution.

From the jekyll page, I'm trying to make a jQuery function that call for GA and Mixpanel.track within the same click trigger. I need to called the id that dynamically generate by liquid tag.

I'm successfully send to GA, here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a[target='_blank']").click(function() {
        var downloadSource = $(this).attr("id");
        ga('send', 'event', 'download', downloadSource, 'download' );
    });

});
```

The problem is how to add mixpanel.track inside that function so it can track the same trigger link?

I've tried to modified my code into this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a[target='_blank']").click(function() {
        var downloadSource = $(this).attr("id");
        ga('send', 'event', 'download', downloadSource, 'download' );

        mixpanel.track('download', downloadSource);
    });

});
```

It failed to send event to mixpanel. So how to add mixpanel.track inside that function so it can track the same trigger link?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.